# Why does reverseString print undefined when console.log Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reverse a string but I will get a value as follows when i console.log in chrome console:

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  let newString = "";
  for (let i = str.length; i + 1 > 0; i--) {
    newString = newString + str[i];
  }
  return (newString);
}

console.log(reverseString("hello there"));
```

Why is there undefined in front of the reverse string?

Answer (score 1):

You start at an `i` of `str.length`. On the first iteration, `str[i]` resolves to `str[str.length]`, but strings are zero-indexed, not one-indexed, so that will always be `undefined`. Start at `str.length - 1` instead:

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  let newString = "";
  for (let i = str.length - 1; i + 1 > 0; i--) {
    newString = newString + str[i];
  }
  return (newString);
}
console.log(reverseString("hello there"));
```